# Extracting directory / file names in a Makefile

Tags: c#, makefile, protocol-buffers

Could someone help me understand the behaviour of the makefile, below? To give some context, I am trying to generated a series of c# classes from a set of .proto files. The proto files are contained within a directory structure which i want to mirror in the output. So, assuming my source files are in a folder called 'Source' and I am outputting into a folder called 'Generated', if a file resides in:

'Source/Foo/Bar/myfile.protoc'

then output should be:

'Generated/Foo/Bar/MyFile.cs'.

This seems simple enough however I am seeing some strange behaviour when using dir/notdir in the make file. here is an example:

```
# Makefile to build message definitions within this repo
PROTOS:= SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto

withVariables:
    for proto in $(PROTOS)  ;   do \
    echo $(dir $$proto) ; \
    echo $(notdir $$proto) ; \
    done;

hardCoded:
    echo $(dir ./SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto)
    echo $(notdir ./SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto)
    echo $(dir ./SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto)
    echo $(notdir ./SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto)
```

Essentially, when I have the collection of file names in a variable and try to iterate them, dir/notdir does not seem to recognised the separators in the path. Running Make hardCoded here gives:

```
./SourceFiles/Module_1/
BasicMessage.proto
./SourceFiles/Module_2/
BasicMessage.proto
```

which is what i would expect. However, running withVariables gives:

```
./
SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto
./
SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto
```

I am still pretty new to make files, so I am probably missing something simple, but if anyone can explain why these two examples behave differently, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipes are expanded by make before being passed to the shell. So, in the recipe of `withVariables`, the `$(dir $$proto)`  and `$(notdir $$proto)` are expanded to `./` and `$proto`, respectively. The recipe becomes:

```
for proto in SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto; do \
echo ./ ; \
echo $proto ; \
done;
```

which logically produces the output you see. You cannot use make functions in your recipes and expect them to be executed by the shell. Instead you can invoke the standard `dirname` and `basename` external programs from your recipe:

```
withVariables:
    for proto in $(PROTOS); do \
        echo $$(dirname $$proto); \
        echo $$(basename $$proto); \
    done
```

The recipe is expanded by make as:

```
for proto in SourceFiles/Module_1/BasicMessage.proto SourceFiles/Module_2/BasicMessage.proto; do \
    echo $(dirname $proto); \
    echo $(basename $proto); \
done
```

which, when executed by the shell, outputs:

```
host> make withVariables
SourceFiles/Module_1
BasicMessage.proto
SourceFiles/Module_2
BasicMessage.proto
```